# Ajax GridView - multiple select support

Tags: javascript, gridview

I am looking for a Ajax Grid control that can be used easily for binding data using js methods. I have tried using the `GridView` in `AjaxDataControls`, and it's okay - but I am also looking for multiple select support in the `GridView`. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ExtJs](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/binding-with-classes.html).  It has the best Grid i've seen so far. It supports XML and JSON and conversion from basic HTML tables.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Dojo Grid:

- Good write up in [Dojo 1.2 Grid](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/14/dojo-12-grid/) and in [New Features in Dojo Grid 1.2](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/10/22/new-features-in-dojo-grid-12/).
- Tons of code examples in [dojox.grid.tests](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/) (warning: this link points directly to the nightlies ⇒ the Dojo code is packaged for debugging purposes, not for performance).